# How can I convert words with umlaut like NeusÃ¤ÃŸ into the correct word Neusäß in swift

Tags: ios, swift, string

As described in the title I have Strings with umlaut like "ÃŸ", "Ã¶", "Ã_" etc. instead of the corresponding "ß", "ö", "ü" ... 
how can I convert the strings into the correct format. 
I already saw: 
    `let str = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "ÃŸ", with: "ß")
str = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "Ã¶", with: "ö")` 
etc... but as I have multiple strings and variables I am looking for an easier way to convert it. Thank you!

EDIT:
I get the data from a mysql database, where another app (not mine and fairly old) writes to it. I want to get the data from mysql, convert it and put into my firebase database. Everything works except the conversion.

Comment: Look like a string encoding problem. The two bytes that make up "ß" in UTF-8 correspond to "ÃŸ" in the ISO Latin 1 encoding. How did you get the "ÃŸ" string?

Comment: I get it from a mysql database, where another app (not mine and fairly old) writes to it. I want to get the data from mysql, convert it and put into my firebase database. Everything works except the conversion.

Comment: You should not convert the characters like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems the character sequence `NeusÃ¤ÃŸ` is a UTF-8 byte sequence of `Neusäß` (`<4e657573 c3a4c39f>`) re-interpreted as Windows-1252.

So, you can try some conversion in reverse:

- Get the byte sequence as Windows-1252
- Re-interpret the byte sequence as UTF-8

Something like this:

```
extension String {
    func reencode(from: String.Encoding, to: String.Encoding) -> String? {
        guard let data = self.data(using: from) else {return nil}
        print(data as NSData)
        return String(data: data, encoding: to)
    }
}

"NeusÃ¤ÃŸ".reencode(from: .windowsCP1252, to: .utf8) //->"Neusäß"
"ÃŸ".reencode(from: .windowsCP1252, to: .utf8) //->"ß"
"Ã¶".reencode(from: .windowsCP1252, to: .utf8) //->"ö"
```

But, when this sort of encoding mismatching happens, some information of the original data would be lost and cannot be recovered by *conversion*.

I do not know if this is caused by such a data-loss, but the extension method above cannot convert `"Ã_"`.

```
"Ã_".reencode(from: .windowsCP1252, to: .utf8) //-> nil
```

You should better check the settings about encodings and the way you get the data from MySQL.

Comment: `.windowsCP1254` is another possibility for the given input, but `.windowsCP1252` seems more likely. A bit dangerous to do the conversion on frontend though...

Comment: Works like a charm. yes it would be possible to convert it directly in the php, which gives the data. But in special cases I needed the old form. Thank you!